# Python Code for List of Month Names starting with current month

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am looking for a cleaner, more pythonic way to get a list of the name of the months starting with the current month and ending 12 months later.

For example, it's December so my list should be

```py
['Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov']
```

Here is how I'm currently doing it:

```
from datetime import datetime

currentMonth = datetime.now().month

if (currentMonth == 1):
    theList = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
elif (currentMonth == 2):
    theList = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan']
elif (currentMonth == 3):
    theList = ['Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb']
elif (currentMonth == 4):
    theList = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
elif (currentMonth == 5):
    theList = ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
elif (currentMonth == 6):
    theList = ['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
elif (currentMonth == 7):
    theList = ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
elif (currentMonth == 8):
    theList = ['Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']
elif (currentMonth == 9):
    theList = ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
elif (currentMonth == 10):
    theList = ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
elif (currentMonth == 11):
    theList = ['Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']
elif (currentMonth == 12):
    theList = ['Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov']

print(theList)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding month names - delegate all the work to respective libraries.

I would suggest 2 approaches:

- [`calendar.month_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr)

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  from calendar import month_abbr

  def get_forward_month_list():
      month = datetime.now().month   # current month number
      return [month_abbr[(month % 12 + i) or month] for i in range(12)]
  ```
- [`dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta)

  ```
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

  def get_forward_month_list():
      now = datetime.now()
      return [(now + relativedelta(months=i)).strftime('%b') for i in range(12)]
  ```

---

Both approaches will return the expected/needed list of month names:

```
print(get_forward_month_list())
['Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov']
```

Comment: Awesome. I thought there was a way to do it utilizing a library. Thank you.

Comment: @Christopher, you're welcome

Comment: To avoid modulos and ors and complicated expressions for skipping the empty [0] I would use `return month_abbr[month:] + month_abbr[1:month]` instead

Comment: @Christopher said "*I thought there was a way to do it utilizing a library.*"  The only thing the library did was provide the `month_abbr` list. It's the same as your first definition of `theList`, so, in terms of coding, all the library did was save a few characters of typing. — Thinking at a higher level though, libraries guarantee getting the same abbreviations as everyone else, and that should the world decide to make changes to the official abbreviation list (e.g. add a new month) your code will handle it with no changes on your part. And if a user prefers French, that's what they'll see.

Comment: @njzk2 Absolutely. I've been staring at `(month % 12 + i) or month` for far too long. I still don't get why the naive solution `(month + i) % 12`  wouldn't work? What am I missing?

Comment: Oh nm, lol. I knew `0` didn't work from the start, then forgot it at some point.

Comment: @njzk2 — Another good reason for not using the `%12` method is that it makes an assumption about the number of elements in a list obtained from a library.  In this case, I doubt a thirteenth month will be added anytime soon, but as a general principle, it's not good to make assumptions about what something else provides.  Even if the library were something that the program's author maintains, it's still not good to use hard-wired numbers.  Changing the library would require changing this code.  `0`, `1`, and `many` are the only good numbers to use when programming.

Comment: Am I missing something? `month = 9

for i in range (12):
    print((month % 12 + i) or month)` yields 9 through 20.

Comment: It's a little clunky, but `(month +1+i)%12 -1` should work.

Comment: @JollyJoker I was wondering the same thing, until I looked at the doc and realized that empty 0 is always there

Answer (score 9):

First of call, `theList` is not a good name for that variable. You can be much more specific in your case! I'd suggest `months`.

Also, there is no need to have all of those lists hard-coded in your script. Use a single instance of that list, and then create modified versions as you need them.

Edit: I was absolutely sure that there has to be a Python library that has the names already covered, but failed to find it. [RomanPerekhrest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233705/92478) beat me here and correctly identified [`calendar.month_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr) as the way to go.

A [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) like below could to the trick:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
current_month = datetime.now().month - 1
print([months[(current_month + i) % 12] for i in range(12)])
```

Or you can use [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) to get it even more comfortable:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
current_month = datetime.now().month - 1
print(months[current_month:]+months[:current_month])
```

If performance ever should become a concern, you could create a look-up using a dictionary  beforehand, so that the computation does not have to be repeated:

```
MONTHS_TO_COME = {i+1: months[i:]+months[:i] for i in range(12)}

# ... other code ...

month = datetime.now().month
print(MONTHS_TO_COME[month])
```

Oh, and maybe have a look at the "official" [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), aka PEP 8, for some hints on idiomatic formatting commonly found in Python code (e.g. `lower_case_with_underscores` in variable names).

Answer (score 8):

Shamelessly ripping off @RomanPerekhrest 's answer. You can't rotate a list in Python but you can a deque, and the collections module always needs more love:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import month_abbr
from collections import deque

def get_forward_months():
    months = deque(month_abbr[1:])
    months.rotate(1-datetime.now().month)
    return months
```

Comment: I don't think you need the list comprehension. `months = deque(month_abbr[1:])` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MattM. Yes, even better, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the built-in `strftime` rather than defining your own list of strings:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date.today()
months = []
for _ in range (12):
    months.append(date.strftime("%b"))
    date = date.replace(month=(date.month % 12 + 1))
```

Because someone will always complain when you can't find a way to do a loop like this as a list comprehension, here's a way to do it in a single line of code with a cheesy `timedelta` (this doesn't work for arbitrarily long sequences because 30 days isn't exactly one month, but for your use case the rounding errors won't add up enough to matter):

```
months = [(datetime.date.today().replace(day=15) + datetime.timedelta(days=30*n)).strftime("%b") for n in range(12)]
```

although to make this readable I think you'd want to break it up a little:

```
months = [
    (datetime.date.today().replace(day=15) + 
     datetime.timedelta(days=30*n)).strftime("%b") 
     for n in range(12)
]
```

IMO the `for` loop version is cleaner.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can work with a single list
`theList = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']`

What you want to do is to start with a certain index and then add 12 elements to a list while you have `index%12`. So you can do something like

```
from datetime import datetime

theList = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
month = datetime.now().month
newList = list()
for i in range(12):
    newList.append(theList[(month-1+i)%12])

print(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to some of the others here.  However, it doesn't use loops, math, conditional logic, or hard-coded month names.  That should make it more resistant to bugs.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

monthList = lambda month: \
    calendar.month_abbr[month:] + \
    calendar.month_abbr[1:month]

currentMonth = datetime.now().month

print(monthList(currentMonth))
```

The output:

```
['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
```

This uses Python's `calendar` module, because it includes a `month_abbr` list with all the month name abbreviations.  It has an empty string at element 0 and the month names are in elements 1–12.

```
['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

The simplest solution is to use slices of that list, taking into account that the elements needed start with index 1.

What this solution does is take a slice of `month_abbr` starting with the current month to the end of the list (`calendar.month_abbr[month:]`) and appends a slice of `month_abbr` starting with the first month ***up to but not including*** the current month (`calendar.month_abbr[1:month]`).

### Localization

An additional benefit to using the `calendar.month_abbr` list is that it is ***localized***.  If the locale in the program's environment changes to one with a different language, then the month abbreviation list automatically contains the names of months in that language.  For example, updating the above code to switch locales, the following code will print the month list in the language of the default locale (English in this example), then print them in German and Hebrew (as an example of non-Latin script).

```
import calendar
import locale
from datetime import datetime

monthList = lambda month: \
    calendar.month_abbr[month:] + \
    calendar.month_abbr[1:month]

currentMonth = datetime.now().month

print(locale.getlocale(),
      monthList(currentMonth))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
print(locale.getlocale(),
      monthList(currentMonth))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'he_IL')
print(locale.getlocale(),
      monthList(currentMonth))
```

The output:

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8') ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
('de_DE', 'ISO8859-1') ['Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
('he_IL', 'ISO8859-8') ['אוק', 'נוב', 'דצמ', 'ינו', 'פבר', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יונ', 'יול', 'אוג', 'ספט']
```

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better if your observations preceded your alternate code.

Comment: Thanks!  How would it be better?  Do you mean I should put the explanation of using and slicing`calendar.month_abbr` before the code?  I had originally written it that way. Then I thought the impatient TL;DR crowd (of which I'm a member) might like to see the solution and output as the very first thing, so I rearranged it.  I could be persuaded to arrange it back again, especially if your comment gets a lot of votes.

Comment: Your initial version would have been better, since this sight is about the original posters code and not about alternate solutions.